# Is there a 2.0 SP2 .NET redistributable?

Tags: .net

I'm a bit confused over the .net "redistributables"...

Our C# code uses some API calls that require .net 2.0 sp2. **We do not want to require the user to download anything at the time of installation** (this is a Winforms app with and installer) for various reasons.
We currently include the 2.0 redistributable, and of course the functions requiring sp2 throws.

Is there a redistributable package for 2.0 SP2 to be found somewhere?

If not, what would be the best alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[.NET 2.0 SP2](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=5B2C0358-915B-4EB5-9B1D-10E506DA9D0F&displaylang=en)
or
[.NET 3.5 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=AB99342F-5D1A-413D-8319-81DA479AB0D7&displaylang=en)

Comment: Unfortunately, these are not "redistributables" and therefore may require downloading content at installation time. I edited the question, bolding this requirement to clarify...

Comment: According to http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=396538, that .Net 2.0 SP2 download is the redistributable package. Note however: 'IMPORTANT: After installing the .NET Framework 2.0 SP2 update you should immediately install the update KB959209 to address a set of known application compatibility issues.' So unless you visit your users' workstations and install SP2 yourselves, it looks like they will have to run at least a couple of installers.

Comment: For the .Net 3.5 SP1 installer, scroll down on the page provided in the answer to the 'Instructions' section. There you will find a link to the .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1 (Full Package) (http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/0/e/20e90413-712f-438c-988e-fdaa79a8ac3d/dotnetfx35.exe). Again note that an install of KB959209 is required.